# Accessing an unreturned list within a function in Python without disturbing Scipy

Tags: python, function, scipy

Here is the code I'm working on. I'm trying to find the optimum alpha value to get the minimum MAE/MAD. With `scipy.optimize`, it works quite well. However, when `scipy.optimize` achieves the optimum alpha, it also achieves the forecast values that essentially I'm trying to get to. Is there a way to return or access and store those forecast values named `yPredList` without disturbing the work `scipy.optimize` is doing? Because otherwise I'm going to have to do the forecast calculations from scratch, which is unnecessary. Thanks.

```
import numpy as np 
import scipy.optimize as spop
ObservedSpeeds = [85, 64, 97 ,82, 12, 30, 47, 20, 45, 90, 60, 42, 50, 67, 28] #This is not the actual dataset, I actually have a data set of 525,600.
def ErrorCalc(alpha,ObservedSpeeds):
    yPredList = [0,ObservedSpeeds[0]] #First prediction is 0 and the second prediction is the first observation
    for iters in range(2,len(ObservedSpeeds)):
        yPredList.append(np.multiply((1-alpha),yPredList[iters-1]) + np.multiply(alpha,ObservedSpeeds[iters-1]))
    NewList = [np.abs(y-o) for y,o in zip(yPredList,ObservedSpeeds)]
    NewError = np.mean(NewList)
    return NewError

result = spop.minimize_scalar(ErrorCalc,bounds=[0,1],args=ObservedSpeeds,method='bounded')
alpha = result.x
```

Comment: Can you please provide some data so that it's a completely reproducible example?

Comment: I generate the data randomly in a separate .py file so I don't have a csv file or anything. But it's not important, I think. You can have ObservedSpeeds = [85, 64, 97 ,82, 12, 30, 47, 20, 45, 90, 60, 42, 50], 67, 28], for example, which is the only input, basically. But the original ObservedSpeeds has 525600 data.

Comment: You could make yPredList a global variable.  Will that work for you?

Comment: @UmutC.  Sorry, I realized that right after I posted the comment.  I've edited it.

Comment: Nobody is recommending the declaration of global variables. And I'll use the same alpha fitting method for other functions, as well. I don't know if that'll create a mess. So I'm hesitant and would like to find another way, if possible.

Comment: So you want `yPredList` once, at the end when you know the correct `alpha`?  when you could, in theory run `ErrorCalc` with some changes in the parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are good reason not to use global variables, but occasionally there are good reasons to use them, which is why the language supports them.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as spop
ObservedSpeeds = [85, 64, 97 ,82, 12, 30, 47, 20, 45, 90, 60, 42, 50, 67, 28] #This is not the actual dataset, I actually have a data set of 525,600.
def ErrorCalc(alpha,ObservedSpeeds):
    global yPredList
    yPredList = [0,ObservedSpeeds[0]] #First prediction is 0 and the second prediction is the first observation
    for iters in range(2,len(ObservedSpeeds)):
        yPredList.append(np.multiply((1-alpha),yPredList[iters-1]) + np.multiply(alpha,ObservedSpeeds[iters-1]))
    NewList = [np.abs(y-o) for y,o in zip(yPredList,ObservedSpeeds)]
    NewError = np.mean(NewList)
    return NewError

result = spop.minimize_scalar(ErrorCalc,bounds=[0,1],args=ObservedSpeeds,method='bounded')
alpha = result.x
print(alpha)
print(yPredList)
```

This prints

```
0.371107934483
[0, 85, 77.206733375863138, 84.552171669412104, 83.605040512731307, 57.031841829500955, 47.000110842891587, 47.000069708215037, 36.980129607910214, 39.956367143937683, 58.527956367161963, 59.074243439212907, 52.737856223631674, 51.7218160555691, 57.391671341833728]
```

The heart of the matter is that `minimize_scalar` requires that `ErrorCalc` return a scalar, so if you want to save the the yPredList values, you need some kind of side effect.  If you don't want to make a global variable, you can make your own class.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as spop
ObservedSpeeds = [85, 64, 97 ,82, 12, 30, 47, 20, 45, 90, 60, 42, 50, 67, 28] #This is not the actual dataset, I actually have a data set of 525,600.

class Optimizer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.yPredList = []

    def ErrorCalc(self, alpha,ObservedSpeeds):
        yPredList = [0,ObservedSpeeds[0]] #First prediction is 0 and the second prediction is the first observation
        for iters in range(2,len(ObservedSpeeds)):
            yPredList.append(np.multiply((1-alpha),yPredList[iters-1]) + np.multiply(alpha,ObservedSpeeds[iters-1]))
        NewList = [np.abs(y-o) for y,o in zip(yPredList,ObservedSpeeds)]
        NewError = np.mean(NewList)
        self.yPredList = yPredList
        return NewError

optimizer = Optimizer()
result = spop.minimize_scalar(optimizer.ErrorCalc,bounds=[0,1],args=ObservedSpeeds,method='bounded')
alpha = result.x
print(alpha)
print(optimizer.yPredList)
```

This accomplishes the same thing as global variables, but I think it's pointless, **unless** you want to keep various values of `yPredList` around at the same time.  Then the global variable solution might not be so good, because each call to `ErrorCalc` would overwrite the list.  If you choose to use objects, you'll want a separate one for each optimization problem.

Comment: Well, considering I only want the last `yPredList`, I guess I'll have to use a global variable. Thanks for you suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the different predictionlists you could do something like this

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as spop
from collections import namedtuple

ObservedSpeeds = [85, 64, 97 ,82, 12, 30, 47, 20, 45, 90, 60, 42, 50, 67, 28] #This is not the actual dataset, I actually have a data set of 525,600.
prediction = namedtuple("prediction", "error yPredList alpha")

class Optimizer():

    def __init__(self, ObservedSpeeds):
        self.predictions = []
        self.ObservedSpeeds = ObservedSpeeds

    def ErrorCalc(self, alpha,):
        ObservedSpeeds = self.ObservedSpeeds
        yPredList = [0,ObservedSpeeds[0]] #First prediction is 0 and the second prediction is the first observation
        for iters in range(2,len(ObservedSpeeds)):
            yPredList.append(np.multiply((1-alpha),yPredList[iters-1]) + np.multiply(alpha,ObservedSpeeds[iters-1]))
        NewList = [np.abs(y-o) for y,o in zip(yPredList,ObservedSpeeds)]
        NewError = np.mean(NewList)
        self.predictions.append(prediction(NewError, yPredList, alpha))
        return NewError

    def get_last_prediction(self):
        return self.predictions[-1]

    def get_last_error(self):
        return get_last_prediction().error

    def get_last_yPredlist(self):
        return self.get_last_prediction().yPredList

    def get_last_alpha(self):
        return self.get_last_prediction().alpha

optimizer = Optimizer(ObservedSpeeds)
result = spop.minimize_scalar(optimizer.ErrorCalc,bounds=[0,1],method='bounded')
alpha = result.x
print(alpha)
print(optimizer.get_last_yPredlist())
print(optimizer.get_last_alpha())
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to collect all or the latest value calculated during the `minimize` operation, or would you be happy with a new `ErrorCalc` with the final `alpha`?

To collect the values during the iteration, you could write the value to any mutable object.  A global has been suggested, as well as an object attribute.

Here I save it to a dictionary; a list would have worked just as well

```
In [261]: def foo(alpha):
     ...:     a2 = alpha**2
     ...:     bar['save']=a2
     ...:     return alpha
     ...: 
In [262]: bar={'save':None}
In [263]: foo(3)
Out[263]: 3
In [264]: bar
Out[264]: {'save': 9}
```

These `scipy` functions allow you to pass variables to your function via the `args` parameter.  You are already doing that with `ObservedSpeeds`. You could add a mutable variable to the args tuple: `args=(ObservedSpeeds, savevar)`

```
In [265]: def foo(alpha, bar):
     ...:     a2 = alpha**2
     ...:     bar.append(a2)
     ...:     return alpha
In [266]: bar = []
In [267]: foo(1,bar)
Out[267]: 1
In [268]: foo(3,bar)
Out[268]: 3
In [269]: bar
Out[269]: [1, 9]
```

When using the `args` feature, make sure you are handling its tuple nature correctly.

If you are happy running `ErrorCalc` again with the final `alpha`, you could add a switch to trigger a different return

```
In [270]: def foo(alpha, flag=False):
     ...:     a2 = alpha**2
     ...:     if flag:
     ...:         return alpha,a2
     ...:     else:
     ...:         return alpha
In [271]: foo(3)
Out[271]: 3
In [272]: foo(3,flag=True)
Out[272]: (3, 9)
```

Comment: Thanks this is a very good approach, but I'd want to not run `ErrorCalc` a one last time. However, this approach would very likely work in other parts of my code as it's very direct. Thank you very much, again.